# Gauss divergence theorem proof problem.

Tags: calculus, divergence-theorem

I am trying to understand the proof of gauss' divergence theorem from my book. Now, there is a statement in the proof which i tried to understand, but I am failing to fully understand its whole meaning. Here is the statement:

$For\; points\; on\; S_2.\\\quad dy\;dx=dS_2\;cos\gamma_2$

Let me mention that $cos\;\gamma_2$ is the direction cosine of normal $\bar n_2$ to $S_2$.
**I have attached a picture for more clarity**:

[image]

Now I do understand that $dS_2$ means small area on $S_2$, but why $cos\;\gamma_2$ after $S_2$? it would have made some sense if $\bar n_2$ would have been beside $dS_2$ making it treat like a vector, but $cos\; \gamma_2$ changes the whole scenario? Can anyone please explain me the presence of $cos\;\gamma_2$?

Comment: Think of it in one dimension less. If you have a curve in the $xz$ plane, then $dx = ds \cos(\gamma)$, where $ds$ is an infinitesimal length, which looks infinitesimally like a hypothenuse of a right triangle (draw a figure).

Comment: in one dimension it makes sense,  but in 2 dimension , $dx\;dy$ together would make a small area and not a small line.

Comment: It is hard to explain this without drawing a figure. If you take in infinitesimal square tangent to the surface, then you can find $2$ orthogonal directions tangent to that square, say $v_1$ and $v_2$, where $v_1$ is parallel to the $xy$ plane, while $v_2$ is possibly not parallel to the $xy$ plane. As a result, you only get a correction to the surface area coming from $v_2$, and not from $v_1$. For $v_2$, it is as I described in my previous comment.

Comment: I get it now! We can actually think in terms of vector components, like any vector has two orthogonal components, likewise, infinitesimal area can also be assumed to have two components, and the component on $xy$ plane can be thought as $dx\;dy$ and the component on $xz$ plane can be thought as $dS_2\;cos\;\gamma_2$.

Comment: Yes you are approaching a good understanding. You see, infinitesimals appearing in integrals have been made rigorous using the language of differential forms. A $1$-form is a dual of a vector field, so that when you "dot" it with a vector field, you get a real-valued function. A $2$-form at a given point (such as $dx dy$, although usually denoted by $dx \wedge dy$), when you dot it with $2$ tangent vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, it returns a real number, and is skew-symmetric bilinear in $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: As a result, a $2$-form in $\mathbb{R}^3$ actually has $3$ components at any given point, and can be expanded as a linear combination of $dx \wedge dy$, $dx \wedge dz$ and $dy \wedge dz$.

Comment: The branch of mathematics that studies those things is called Differential Geometry (DG). See for instance some of Do Carmo's excellent books, which is where I have learned the topic for the first time. But there are many other references, and many more modern ones (I am not up-to-date with the literature on introductory books to DG). The book by Abbena, Salamon and Gray seems interesting too, as it also contains DG explorations with Mathematica.